# OpenOffice Calc covert binary code to decimal using many cels

Tags: openoffice-calc

I have problem with conversion from binary to decimal value.
I keep every bit of binary number in the another cell so I'm looking for some tip how to connect that number into one row using some automatic function and then use BIN2DEC function.

On the picture I wanted to show you what I want to do. [image: Binary to decimal]

Answer (score 0):

Use something like "=BIN2DEC(CONCATENATE(A1;B1;C1;D1;E1;F1;G1;H1))" to achieve the desired decimal value.